# how to find if all assertTrue passed or anyone failed?

Tags: java, junit

I have a test method like with body like

```
{
    assertTrue("Login failed", somecondition);
    assertTrue("Page not browsing", somecondition);
    assertTrue("Button not found", somecondition);
    //here I want to found whether any assertTrue failed or all are passed
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This works already - if any assertion fails, you get an `AssertionError`. Otherwise, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

Well, i'm not sure I understand, but something like this shall work

```
assertTrue("are my conditions true? {}",condition1 && condition2 && condition3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reach already the line

```
//here I want to found whether any assertTrue failed or all are passed
```

then you know for sure that you have passed all your assertTrue statements.

Answer (score 0):

You both have to use 'assertTrue' method to log an entry in JUnit report, and use your own variables to calculate what you want

```
{
   allPassed = True;

   assertTrue("Login failed", somecondition);
   allPassed = allPassed && somecondition;

   assertTrue("Page not browsing", somecondition);
   allPassed = allPassed && somecondition;

   // ...

   assertTrue("All tests succeeded", allPassed);
}
```